# Employees salary query error

Tags: sql

I am trying to make a report for salaries of a company and I want to show all the employees of the company by using some query like this:

```
select tab1.name, tab1.job,tab1.salary, tab2.discount-days,
       (tab1.salary-((tab1.salary/30)*tab2.discount-days) as 'total' 
from   tab1, 
       tab2 
where  tab2 .date_discount between date_begin and date_end;
```

Here it shows only the employees that have taken discounts between this period but I want to show all the employees of company and if some one have taken a discount show also this in the total.

Please need help to do the query that do show all the employees not only that have discounts

Comment: Can you provide the schema and some sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use LEFT JOIN.

```
select tab1.name, tab1.job,tab1.salary, tab2.discount-days,
       (tab1.salary-((tab1.salary/30)*tab2.discount-days) as 'total' 
from   tab1, 
       tab2 left join tab2  as tab3 on tab2.primary_key = tab3.id.primary_key 
and tab3 .date_discount between date_begin and date_end;
```

If you use left join all the records exist in left side table will come and the matched records from right side table will come.

I think it may work for you.

Comment: There is no tab3 in the question. But yes i agree he needs a left join between tab1 and tab2.

Comment: yes i just noticed the alias of tab3. But again i think a left join between tab1 and tab2 is enough.

Comment: @gefrag But there is no relationship mentioned

Comment: True but i suppose there must be one.

Comment: gefrag & PSR ,would you please write the final query as i still beginner and not good in joins

Comment: @user2746526 try the above query once

Comment: @user2746526 let us know if there is any relationship between tab1 and tab2. if any try left joining them.

`select tab1.name, tab1.job,tab1.salary, tab2.discount-days,
   (tab1.salary-((tab1.salary/30)*tab2.discount-days) as 'total' 
    from tab1 left join tab2 on tab1.PK = tab2.FK`

Comment: ok it work but here " (tab1.salary-((tab1.salary/30)*tab2.discount-days) as 'total' " if days = zero or employee has no discount the value of the total show as null. why i want it to show as a value like i do on calculating total

Comment: @user2746526 if you are working on sql server you can use ISNULL () function. ISNULL((tab1.salary-((tab1.salary/30)*tab2.discount-days),0) as total will show the value 0 in case of null.